# Authentication system in frontend - backend services

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, frontend, backend

I'm very new in Spring and never really used java for making web. And I'm making a web with a separated frontend and backend services and I'm trying to make an authentication system using Spring Boot Security. How can I do it? Do I put the security on both the service or just one of them? What's the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is subjective and can have too many interpretations based on context. My understanding is that putting security on both front-end and backend is the best way to implement. After a successful backend authentication you should issue a unique cookie to the browser as it allows users to continue using a site without having to log in to every single page. For each subsequent call, the website recognizes the user from cookie data.

You can use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/bb124839(v=exchg.65)) for a better understanding of dual authentication mechanism.